# api.stackoverflow.com down?

Tags: support, status-norepro

I am currently getting errors when trying to access the stack overflow api. I have tried others (superuser and serverfault) and they seem to work. Is this by design or did the api unintentionally go down?

Answer (score 2):

api is back up

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users

while

http://api.stackoverflow.com

will throw 404 as intended